# distribution of apple application on the apple store, binary file

Tags: iphone, ios, binaryfiles

I have uploaded my binary file using the application loader to the apple store, 
the uploaded file is .app, I compress it and I send it, and it was successfully sent.

My question is, when I try to open the .app, I found just the pics and plist and shell of the application, I didn't find the header and implementation files,

the file uploaded just contains the .app file, should it contain other files like .mobileprovision or others????

How will Apple check the code?

Answer (score 3):

**First of all Apple does't check code in reviewing process.**

I am not sure what's the internal process of reviewing the app but they actually review the following.
1. Use of private APIs
2. Crashing of app, start-up time while launching the application.
3. Human Interface guidelines.
4. Privacy of the user, if you are taking private information without actually needing them.
5. Memory leaks and performance issues.
6. Copyright content or copyright images.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry. Application will test app file and approve if it is according to Apple Guideline. Don't worry regarding application header file and implementation files.

Comment: ok, so just the .app file shall be uploaded?, should I upload with it the .mobileprovision and other files?

Answer (score 0):

Usually takes a week before your App get in Review status, really depends on how many Apps they have to review!

Be patient, have a glass of wine and Good luck mate!